# Customizing the navigation bar

Tags: beamer, formatting, navigation

I was wondering how I can customize the sidebar such that it only shows the current section and subsections that I am currently presenting and how can I remove the navigation bar from the title slide.

Comment: Which `beamer` theme(s) are you using? Can you please add to your question a little document showing the relevant settings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hiding other subsections is easy: it's enough to use the `hideothersubsections` option (either for the theme or for the sidebar outer theme). Hiding other sections is not so simple; it involves a redefinition of `\insertverticalnavigation` as implemented in `beamerbasenavigation.sty`. Hiding the navigation bar from the title frame can be achieved using the `plain` option for the frame. The following example code contains the required code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[hideothersubsections]{PaloAlto}

\makeatletter
\def\insertverticalnavigation#1{%
  \vbox{%
    \def\sectionentry##1##2##3##4##5{%
      \ifnum##5=\c@part%
      \def\insertsectionhead{##2}%
      \def\insertsectionheadnumber{##1}%
      \def\insertpartheadnumber{##5}%
      \hbox{{%
        \usebeamerfont{section in sidebar}\usebeamercolor[fg]{section in sidebar}%
          \hyperlink{Navigation##3}{%
          \ifnum\c@section=##1%
            \ifnum\c@subsection=0\relax%
              {\usebeamertemplate{section in sidebar}}%
            \else%
              \ifx\beamer@nav@css\beamer@hidetext%
                {\usebeamertemplate{section in sidebar}}%
              \else%
                {\usebeamertemplate{section in sidebar shaded}}%
              \fi%
            \fi%
          \else
            %{\usebeamertemplate{section in sidebar shaded}}%
          \fi}}}%
      \beamer@currentsubsection=0\relax\fi}%
    \def\slideentry##1##2##3##4##5##6{}%
    \def\beamer@subsectionentry##1##2##3##4##5{%
      \ifnum##1=\c@part%
      \def\insertpartheadnumber{##1}%
      \def\insertsectionheadnumber{##2}%
      \def\insertsubsectionheadnumber{##3}%
      \def\insertsubsectionhead{##5}%
       \beamer@tocifnothide{\ifnum\c@section=##2\ifnum\c@subsection=##3\beamer@nav@css\else\beamer@nav@oss\fi\else\beamer@nav@ooss\fi}%
      {\hbox{{%
        \usebeamerfont{subsection in sidebar}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subsection in sidebar}%
          \hyperlink{Navigation##4}{%
          \ifnum\c@section=##2%
            \ifnum\c@subsection=##3%
              \ifnum\c@subsubsection=0\relax%
                {\usebeamertemplate{subsection in sidebar}}%
              \else%
                {\usebeamertemplate{subsection in sidebar shaded}}%
              \fi%
            \else%
              {\usebeamertemplate{subsection in sidebar shaded}}%
            \fi%
          \else%
            {\usebeamertemplate{subsection in sidebar shaded}}%
          \fi}}}%
      }%
      \fi}%
    \def\beamer@subsubsectionentry##1##2##3##4##5##6{%
      \ifnum##1=\c@part%
      \def\insertpartheadnumber{##1}%
      \def\insertsectionheadnumber{##2}%
      \def\insertsubsectionheadnumber{##3}%
      \def\insertsubsubsectionheadnumber{##3}%
      \def\insertsubsubsectionhead{##6}%
      \beamer@tocifnothide{\ifnum\c@section=##2\ifnum\c@subsection=##3\beamer@nav@css\else\beamer@nav@oss\fi\else\beamer@nav@ooss\fi}%
      {\hbox{{%
        \usebeamerfont{subsubsection in sidebar}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subsubsection in sidebar}%
          \hyperlink{Navigation##5}{%
          \ifnum\c@section=##2%
            \ifnum\c@subsection=##3%
              \ifnum\c@subsubsection=##4%
                {\usebeamertemplate{subsubsection in sidebar}}%
              \else
                {\usebeamertemplate{subsubsection in sidebar shaded}}%
              \fi%
            \else%
              {\usebeamertemplate{subsubsection in sidebar shaded}}%
            \fi%
          \else%
            {\usebeamertemplate{subsubsection in sidebar shaded}}%
          \fi}}}%
      }%
      \fi}%
    %\beamer@currentsubsection=0\relax%
    \dohead%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}
\institute{The Institute}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain] 
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\section{Test section one}
\begin{frame} test frame for section one\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection one one}
\begin{frame} test frame for section one\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection one two}
\begin{frame} test frame for section one\end{frame}

\section{Test section two}
\begin{frame} test frame for section two\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection two one}
\begin{frame} test frame for section two\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection two two}
\begin{frame} test frame for section two\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If hiding sections is quite hard, is there a way to make the navigation sidebar adjust to when I get to future sections.  Basically I have way too many sections and subsections and not all of them are visible.

Comment: @emka I don't understand your question. Please elaborate. Besides, even though hiding sections is a little harder my answer already shows how to do it.

Comment: I have about one dozen sections in my presentation and each section has anywhere between 1 and 5 subsections.  The navigation sidebar does not show all of the sections.  I am using the PaloAlto theme.

Comment: @emka Did you try my code? Using it, when you are, say, in section 3 just that section and its subsections will show in the navigation bar. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: Thanks!  I really appreciate this.  The code seems quite complex.